# Inserting values from multidim. array using PDO takes a long time. Is there a better way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I got an array of 650 rows. Inserting this using PDO takes between 10-15 seconds on my local computer.
That's very slow. Is this because of disk read/write? Or could it be something else?

This is my array (first 4 rows):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 1
    )
)
```

And this is my code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sl_link_store_category (item_a_ID, item_b_ID) VALUES (:item_a_ID, :item_b_ID)");

foreach($my_array as $row) {
    $stmt->execute(array(':item_a_ID' => $row[0], ':item_b_ID' => $row[1]));
}
```

**SOLUTION**

For those who is wondering, her eis my solution for inserting multiple rows
using only one `$stmt->execute`:

```
    $input_arr; // This array one has lots of values

    $sql = "INSERT INTO sl_link_store_category (field_a, field_b) VALUES ";

    $i = 0;
    // I create the query string with unique prepared values
    // I could probably have used a for loop since I'm not using any
    // values from $row
    foreach($input_arr as $row) {
      $i++;
      $sql .= "(:field_a_$i, :field_a_$i), ";
    }

    // Remove the last comma (and white space at the end)  
    $sql = substr(trim($sql), 0, -1);

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    // I need to create a new associative array with field name 
    // matching the prepared values in the SQL statement.
    $i = 0;
    $arr = array();

    foreach($input_arr as $row) {
      $i++;
      $arr[":field_a_$i"] = $row[0];
      $arr[":field_b_$i"] = $row[1];  
    }

    $stmt->execute($arr);
  }
```

Comment: What database engine (MyISAM, InnoDB...) are you using?

Comment: @konforce - I'm using InnobDB.

Comment: then you may want to consider setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` and `sync_binlog=0` in the MySQL configuration on your development machine. This will minimize disk flushing and can speed up your application by many factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it might be that slow can vary based on alot of factors.

Consider using one query to insert multiple records [PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

Comment: Thanks. It got me on the right track. I actually tried it earlier, but didn't get it to work. But now I found the solution. See above.