# INSERT in main foreach() or in separate foreach()?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a cache table which is rebuilt occasionally:

```
$Sql = 'INSERT INTO someTable (...fields...) VALUES (...values...)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$items_to_insert[] = array();

foreach ($item as $i) {
    $details = array();

    // Lots of things here, such as:
    $details[':username'] = $['username'];

    $items_to_insert[] = $details
}

foreach ($items_to_insert as $i) {
    $stmt->execute($i);
}
```

**What should I take into consideration** to decide if it would be better off to run `$stmt->execute()` in the first `foreach` and to eliminate the second `foreach` and the `$items_to_insert` array? Is there any way to have the `execute()` run concurrently with the next `foreach` loop? This is for an application that will likely run on a variety of hardware so **I am not interested in the specific case of benchmarking on my workstation**, but rather **I am interested in learning the intricacies of situation to make better use of PDO best practices.**

Comment: your code as written will not work. name placeholders have to be UNIQUE within any given statement. you're trying to create MULTIPLE `:username` within that one query. If you want to do this sort of query, you'll need unique names, or use `?`-unamed ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be use none of foreach loops. Using sql queries in loop is a very bad idea, and kind of query (insert, select, update or delete) doesn't matter).

What you should to do is to make **one** query using a loop and execute it only once. Unfortunately, PDO doesn't provide any automatic way to do this, so you have to write it manually.

Look at the accepted answer of this question, it does exactly what you need: [**PDO Prepared inserts multiple rows single query**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

Comment: Thank you, but any of those solutions would preclude the use of prepared statements.

Comment: Yes. But there is no onther way. Unless you'll collect all arguments and a lot of placeholders in a loop and again execute it once.

Comment: Why is best practice to not use a SQL query in a loop? I hear this repeated often, but I am not convinced that it applies to a prepared query.

Comment: Prepared query executes each time just like not prepared. So if you have a loop with 100 iterations, query will be executed 100 times. And this may cause database overloading.

Comment: I don't think that is valid for prepared statements. The preparation takes time, but each run of the statement takes no longer than having multiple INSERTS in the same query.

Comment: @dotancohen I've made a benchmark for you. Here is the result: http://joxi.ru/6OnnUdg5CbCgSfnf7bo and here is the code: http://pastebin.com/G5xYdFYR As you can see, using prepared statements in loop is very-very slow. So yes, this is valid for prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks, Hast. I just ran my own benchmarks with slightly modified versions of your code. My results are (much) closer, but the conclusion is the same: don't loop over the `execute()` statement. Thank you. Also, I did not realize that `execute($someArray)` would pop only the amount of values that it needs (as you have done in Case 3), so that one need not have $someArray be an array of arrays. This is a nice trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question has actually nothing to do with PDO but just with common sense. Running useless extra loop would be obviously worse than not running it at all.

However, it matters rather for the overall code quality, while performance-wise you hardly ever notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an all or nothing situation where either they all insert or they all fail.

Consider using Database Transactions for this. Begin your Transaction, move the `insert` up to the other loop and then do a `commit` at the end.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I did wrap the loop in a transaction. Nice suggestion.