# Multiple insert in MySQL table from PHP table

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck on the following problem. I have two php files: One which displays a list of students with a combo box to mark each student as either 'Present' or 'Absent'and another that receives these postings and inserts the values in a MySql table. I am having a problem posting the values of the array `attendance_status[]` resulting in an error: "Array to string conversion". I know it might be something elementary that I am missing but cannot find my way out. These are my two files (I know that it is deprecated and will update accordingly):

index.php

```
?php 
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


require "config.php";
$con = mysql_connect ( DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS );
mysql_select_db ( DBNAME, $con );


?>


<h1 align="center"><font color="black"><b>ATTENDANCE FOR GRADE1</font></b></h1>
<table id="attendance" border="1"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" >
<tr >
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>surname</th>
<th>attendance</th>

</tr>
<?php

   $query = ("SELECT * FROM `b10_18591250_JC`.`STUDENT`");
   $result = mysql_query($query);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{


  echo "<form action=insertattend.php method=POST>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stid type=number value=" .$row['ID']." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stname type=text value=" .$row['NAME']." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stsurname type=text value=" .$row['SURNAME']." </td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<select name=attendance_status[] id=attendance_status>";
echo "<option value=1>Present</option>";
echo "<option value=0>Absent</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 

}

  echo"<input type=submit value=Submit>";
?>
</table>

</form>
```

Posting in this page called insertattend.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "config.php";
$con = mysql_connect ( DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS );
mysql_select_db ( DBNAME, $con );

$stid = $_POST["stid"];
$attendance_status = $_POST["attendance_status"];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (ID, STUDENT_ID, ATTENDANCE) VALUES
(NULL, '$stid', '$attendance_status')") or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: attendance_status is array you are trying to save it directly

Comment: Seriously? mysql_*? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are posting an array of attendance_status and you should loop that.

```
<?php 
 while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{


  echo "<form action=insertattend.php method=POST>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stid[] type=number value=" .$row['ID']." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stname type=text value=" .$row['NAME']." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=stsurname type=text value=" .$row['SURNAME']." </td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<select name=attendance_status[] id=attendance_status>";
echo "<option value=1>Present</option>";
echo "<option value=0>Absent</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 

}
?>

<?php 
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "config.php";
$con = mysql_connect ( DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS );
mysql_select_db ( DBNAME, $con );

$stid = $_POST["stid"];
$attendance_status = $_POST["attendance_status"];

for($i=0;$i<count($attendance_status);$i++){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (ID, STUDENT_ID, ATTENDANCE) VALUES
   (NULL, $stid[$i], $attendance_status[$i])") or die (mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: Execute insert statement inside a loop is not a good approach it degrade performance and slow down the system.
instead you can generate query in a loop and insert outside the loop see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459515/is-there-an-alternate-to-using-a-for-loop-to-insert-multiple-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by declaring a variable for each result you have. 
For example, $id = $row['ID'] and them inserting this value to string you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need loop to your array.

```
 <?php 
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require "config.php";
    $con = mysql_connect ( DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS );
    mysql_select_db ( DBNAME, $con );

    $stid = $_POST["stid"];
    $attendance_status = $_POST["attendance_status"];
    $size = sizeof($attendance_status);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $size ; $i++ ){
        $value = $attendance_status[$i]; 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (ID, STUDENT_ID, ATTENDANCE) VALUES
        (NULL, '$stid', '$value')") or die (mysql_error());
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said. You are trying to save an array of data in a single work step. I've slightly restructured your files and changed the stid input to array.

What insertattend.php does:

- creates the sql insert query header
- loops for each studentid, gets the key and value from each studentid
- concats the values to the header
- and trims away the last colon on the last concat

after that, you'll get a sql string like

```
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (ID, STUDENT_ID, ATTENDANCE) VALUES
    (NULL, '1', '0'),
    (NULL, '2', '1'),
    ...
    (NULL, '26', '1')
```

wich you can execute with mysql_query().

> **But be aware!**
>
> You are using unescaped input from the post and therefore vulnerable for **sql injections**!
>
> Read this for further information:
>
> [SQL Injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
>
> [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

---

```
<?php // index.php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require "config.php";
    $con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con);
    $query  = ("SELECT * FROM `b10_18591250_JC`.`STUDENT`");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<h1 align="center"><font color="black"><b>ATTENDANCE FOR GRADE1</font></b></h1>
<form action=insertattend.php method=POST>
    <table id="attendance" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>surname</th>
            <th>attendance</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input name=stid[] type=number value="<?= $row['ID'] ?>"</td>
                <td><input name=stname type=text value="<?= $row['NAME'] ?>"</td>
                <td><input name=stsurname type=text value="<?= $row['SURNAME'] ?>"</td>
                <td>
                    <select name=attendance_status[] id=attendance_status>
                        <option value=1>Present</option>
                        <option value=0>Absent</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </table>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>

<?php // insertattend.php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require "config.php";
    $con = mysql_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con);

    $ids    = $_POST["stid"];
    $status = $_POST["attendance_status"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (ID, STUDENT_ID, ATTENDANCE) VALUES";

    foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
        $sql .= "(NULL, '$value', '$status[$key]'),";
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');

    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```