# Insert multiple rows with PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I would like to know if it is possible to insert multiple rows using one prepared statement.
Below is an example of how I would normally insert one row into the db:

```
$params=array();
$params[':val1']="val1";
$params[':val2']="val2";
$params[':val3']="val3";
$sql="INSERT INTO table VALUES (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (:val1,:val2,:val3)";
$stmt=DB::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

The values I want to insert will come from an array, for example:
    $values[0]['val1'];
    $values[0]['val2'];
    $values[0]['val3'];
    $values[1]['val1'];
    $values[2]['val2'];

etc.

This code may have to insert a few hundred rows at once, I thought about creating a loop to create hundreds of params and then append the sql statement with an extra insert for each row but I thought there must be a better way. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any problem with this insert at the moment?

Comment: No, this code for a single insert works fine, I would like to know how best to go about inserting multiple rows with placeholders this way.

Comment: From where do you get the values to be inserted?

Comment: just loop over your multiple parameters and execute. Did you try that?

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query?rq=1

Answer (score 33):

The first important thing to say is that you **can** insert multiple rows thanks to only *one* `INSERT` query

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
       ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
       ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
       ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
       ('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
       -- and so on...
```

Once you know that, you're able to get a good solution with PDO (for instance).
You have to keep in mind that you want a complete `prepare` and `execute` process (in term of security, you have to pass each parameter separately).

Let's say you have rows to insert structured as follow:

```
$rows = array(
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), // row 1 to insert
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), // row 2 to insert
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')  // row 3 to insert
              // and so on ...
);
```

Your goal is to have this result as a **prepared query**:

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?),
       (?, ?, ?),
       (?, ?, ?)
```

With its corresponding **execute**:

```
PDOStatement::execute(array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'));
```

Well, you *only* have to do it now:

```
$rows = array(
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')
);

$row_length = count($rows[0]);
$nb_rows = count($rows);
$length = $nb_rows * $row_length;

/* Fill in chunks with '?' and separate them by group of $row_length */
$args = implode(',', array_map(
                                function($el) { return '('.implode(',', $el).')'; },
                                array_chunk(array_fill(0, $length, '?'), $row_length)
                            ));

$params = array();
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   foreach($row as $value)
   {
      $params[] = $value;
   }
}

$query = "INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ".$args;
$stmt = DB::getInstance()->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

And... That's it!

This way, each param is treated separately, which is what you want (security, security, security!) and all of it, in a dynamic way, with only one `INSERT` query

---

If you have too many rows to insert (see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)), you should `execute` one by one

```
$rows = array(
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), // row 1 to insert
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), // row 2 to insert
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')  // row 3 to insert
              // and so on ...
);

$args = array_fill(0, count($rows[0]), '?');

$query = "INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (".implode(',', $args).")";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
   $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

Comment: I'm missing something here or is that not going to work? ``"INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (".implode(',', $args).")";`` would become ``"INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";`` for two rows, which is invalid?

``(?,?,?,?,?,?)`` should have been ``(?,?,?),(?,?,?)``

Comment: @JCM You're right, i'm a bit surprised no one has mentioned it before. It is now corrected. Thanks for your remark !

Comment: @Edward There is a reference link to explain "too many" in the answer

Comment: Ahh sorry I missed that, thank you! Anyways, 5 years later and you’re still supporting this answer, awesome!

Answer (score 7):

If your table is transactional (for example an InnoDB), you can use a [Transaction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) to speed up your insertions. A transaction has also the advantage of [roll backs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php).

```
$pdo = DB::getInstance();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:val1, :val2, :val3)');

$pdo->beginTransaction();

// The queries are not executed yet, but pushed to a transaction "stack"
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $stmt->execute([
        ':val1' => $value['val1'],
        ':val2' => $value['val2'],
        ':val3' => $value['val3'],
    ]);
}

// Executes all the queries "at once"
$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: Would this lead to single insert query so it is still very fast for thousands of inserts at once?

Comment: @kentor No, but it's still fast due to the nature of prepared statements, which become more efficient as you fire more of them.

Answer (score 6):

If you're only inserting a few hundred rows, I'd favor simpler code like the following. Prepare a single-row INSERT statement, and then loop over your data array, executing the prepared query once for each row.

```
$rows = array(
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), // row 1 to insert
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), // row 2 to insert
              array('abc', 'def', 'ghi')  // row 3 to insert
              // and so on ...
);

$params = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($rows[0]), "?"));

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($params)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); // rely on exceptions for error detection

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

MySQL does support multi-row INSERT syntax of course, so you could try putting that together.

```
$params = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($rows[0]), "?"));

$tuples = "(" . implode("),(", array_fill(0, count($rows), $params)) . ")";

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES $tuples";

$values = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $rows);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute($values);
```

But if you try to create a single INSERT statement with as many tuples as the items in your data array, you might accidentally generate an SQL statement that is longer than the [maximum packet length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).

If you have thousands of rows, enough so that executing a prepared statement one row at a time is too much overhead, you should use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 3):

To keep your code, you have to make a loop for executing all insertions you need :

```
$array_params = array();
$params[':val1']="val1 1";
$params[':val2']="val1 2";
$params[':val3']="val1 3";
$array_params[] = $params;

$params[':val1']="val2 1";
$params[':val2']="val2 2";
$params[':val3']="val2 3";
$array_params[] = $params;

$sql="INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (:val1,:val2,:val3)";
$stmt=DB::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
foreach($array_params as $params)
{
  $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

But its possible to execute multiple insertions with one query like `INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ("val1","val2","val3"),("val4","val5","val6"),("val7","val8,"val9")`, by using something like this to build the query:

```
$all_inserts = array( array('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),array('val4', 'val5', 'val6'));
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ';
$rows = array();
foreach ($all_inserts as $one_insert)
{
   $rows[] = '('.implode(',', $pdo->quote($one_insert).')';
}
$sql .= ' '.implode(',', $rows);
$pdo->query($sql);
```

Comment: Actually, that last answer does not use bound parameters so is not as secure as I need it to be.  In the first, the prepare is happening outside of the loop so does not work.