# Inserting arrays into SQL with for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a form on a page which is created by a for loop.

```
$scripte = ($_POST["scriptake"]);
$scriptot = ($_POST["scriptot"]);
include 'config.php';

echo '<h2>'.$scripte.' Equipment</h2>';
echo '<h2>Total Hours '.$scriptot.'</h2>';

echo '<table class="table table-responsive">
        <tr>
          <form action="equiptest.php" method="post">
          <th>Script Hour</th>
          <th>Equipment Required</th>
          <th>Stage</th>
        </tr>';
$x = 1;
$p = 1;
$r = 1;
while($x <= $scriptot ) {
  echo "<tr>
          <td>".$x++."</td>
          <td>
            <input name='equip[".$r++."]'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name='stage[".$p++."]'>
            <input name='ohyeah' type='hidden' value= '".$scriptot."'>
          </td>
        </tr>";
}
echo '<tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </td>
      </tr>
      </form>
     </table>';
```

As you can see a form with inputs is created with a for loop. The values from the form are collected in an array equip[] and stage[]. With have a counter for the index if that makes sense. The form is then submitted to the following script.

```
include 'config.php';
$scriptot = ($_POST["ohyeah"]);
$y = 1;

$r= 1;

foreach($_POST['equip'] as $key => $value) {    
  foreach($_POST['stage'] as $key => $stage) {
    $query = $con->stmt_init();
    $statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO dgam_equip 
                                (equiplist,stage)  VALUES (?,?)");

    $statement->bind_param('ss',$value,$stage);
    $statement->execute();
  }
}

echo 'success';
//bind result variables to be printed
$statement->close();

echo '<br><br><br><br><br>';
```

I'm trying to then insert the arrays into a database.

ID | Equiplist |Stage
ID    equip[]    stage[]

I am trying to nest a foreach loop or get the arrays added in the correct row. I can get the row in but the data excecutes a huge number of times. I am guessing that is because the foreach loop is excecuting the second foreach loop
What is the correct way to put this kind of data into a database. I am trying to set an array up first but am struggling.

Comment: Edit and remove the unnecessary html, the only relevant thing is the actual loop, you should also improve the indentation of your code so its easier to read.

Comment: sorry but in past i got 6 down votes for not putting the code  up. il take off now

Comment: Just use one loop and use the index to access both arrays. You can get the size of the arrays using ```sizeof``` and you might want to compare the size of the arrays before looping over them

Comment: the arrays will be the same size everytime

Comment: Your tags are wrong: `<table ...><tr><form ..>...</tr>`. They are not matched correctly and `<form>` is not [valid content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) for `<tr>`

Comment: You should not trust user input, so it might change, I'm just being paranoid  :P

Comment: i get the correct data if i echo and can put db. it just goes a silly amount of times. if i am expecting 60 rows i get 60 X 60 rows. The loop is looping over the loop

Comment: As I said, use one for loop to access both arrays at the same time.

Comment: ca i have a quick snippet to see what yyou are getting at. I have only used the simplest of these loops

Comment: Note that you just need to call `prepare()` and `bind_param()` **once**, before you start your first loop. Just create a couple of placeholders for you parameters ie `$stage` and `$equip` before calling `bind_param()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $length = count($_POST['stage']);
  $stages = $_POST['stage'];
  $equips = $_POST['equip'];
  $stage = '';
  $equip = '';
  $query = $con->stmt_init();
  $statement = $con->prepare( "INSERT INTO dgam_equip (equiplist,stage)  VALUES (?,?) ");
  $statement->bind_param('ss', $equip, $stage);

  for( $i=0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
     $stage = $stages[$i];
     $equip = $equips[$i];

     if ( ! empty($stage) ) $statement->execute();

   }
```

It can be optimized to take all the values in one query.

Comment: Is prepare needed in every step? :)

Comment: You should not call `prepare()` and `bind_param()` inside the loop, just do this once before starting the loop ie: `$stage = null; $equip = null; $statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ..."); $statement->bind_param('ss', $equip, $stage); for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { $stage = $stages[$i]; $equip = $equips[$i]; $statement->execute(); }`

Comment: This works thankyou. Had to change a couple of bits that were specific to my code but you would not have known these. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I have also take @cyclone advice it does not seem a good idea to call that everytime - upvote for that if it lets me. I dont have enough points to edit anwser as it is a good point

Comment: That is why I said it can be optimized. I just wanted to show how to change your current code which also has the command inside the loop.

Comment: What I usually do is create something similar to described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680494/insert-multiple-rows-with-pdo-prepared-statements). Collect the `INSERT INTO` om an array, then use `array_chunk()` on it and loop over the chunks to prevent hitting max length limitations. It seemed too much to go into to answer the initial problem. Adjusted the code to reflect the suggested change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$equipes = $_POST['equip'];
$stages = $_POST['stage'];

$query = $con->stmt_init();
$statement = $con->prepare( "INSERT INTO dgam_equip (equiplist,stage)  VALUES (?,?) ");

for ($i = 0, $total = count($equipes); $i < $total; $i = $i + 100) {
        $insertEquipe = array_slice($equipes, $i, 100);
        $insertStage = array_slice($stages, $i, 100);
        $conn->beginTransaction();

        foreach ($insertEquipe as $equipe) {
           foreach ($insertStage as $stage) {
               $stmt->bindValue(1, $equipe);
               $stmt->bindValue(2, $stage);
               $stmt->execute();
            }  
        }
        $conn->commit();
    }
```

Comment: This still contains the error that there will be n x n inserts instead of n

Comment: He used `foreach` twice because he thought that was the way to address two arrays. However, the arrays have paired values with the same array-index in each array. They can be addressed in one `foreach`, creating n rows to send to database.