# Loop through POST array and update database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a PHP page that dynamically generates forms based on the data received from a MySQL database. For example, say there is an entry for the Logo URL, it would be as follows:

```
configName = MainLogoURL; configValue = "blah";
```

That's the general idea. The task that I'm struggling with is updating the database, all of the data is sent through a POST request. The end result is like this

```
Array ( 
       Array ( configName => "MainLogoURL", configValue => "BLAH 2" )
)
```

And obviously there would be more arrays in that structure for each variable. If there is a more efficient way then could you please let me know (and how to do it) or could you just let me know how to do it.

Comment: Have to structured your database table for each of these post values?

Comment: Each value follows the same structure, so yes it is.

Comment: Than you just have to make use of foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) and fetch all the submitted values.

Comment: But how would I make that into one single MySQL query ? I'm trying to make this as efficient as possible.

Comment: use PDO and prepare statements http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Is there any chance someone can give me an example ? I've never used PDO before, I wouldn't know what to search or where to begin.

Comment: just for me... after this i can help... you have an post array structured like (in your question) and you would like to update your db with these informations ?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like some people sayed... use pdo, in your case this should look like:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (configName, configValue) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

$myArray = Array ( 
   Array ( "configName" => "MainLogoURL", "configValue" => "BLAH 2" )
)


foreach($myArray as $arr)
{
    $name  = $arr['configName'];
    $value = $arr['configValue'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

posted this because you sayed you want to have a sample :)

Comment: of course if you want to update you have to change the statement :)

Comment: you may have a look at [pdo stored procedur](https://www.google.de/#q=pdo+stored+procedure&safe=off) this looks like you can do some stuff to get it better running... in case there are to many array entrys :) but im still happy that i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

As Yatin said, `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)` is a good start.

You should take a look at the [MySQL documentation for `REPLACE` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). That should allow you to insert multiple values with a single statement.

The [PHP manual has PDO examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to get you started, and there are a couple of working [PDO multiple insert examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query).