# More efficient way of inserting data into mysql using PDo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Ok so I execute the following code for inserting data into database:

```
$db_conn->beginTransaction();
$query = $db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable(name, user) VALUES(:name, :user)');
foreach($UploadData AS $DataValue)
{
    $query->execute(array(':name' => $DataValue['Name'],':user' =>$_SESSION['user']));
}
$db_conn->commit();
```

Now in this code block `execute()` runs `100s` time if I have that much data. Like before I use to do with basic `mysqli` `concatenation` and executes the query only once.

Will that can be done here with PDO also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL = 'INSERT INTO mytable (name, user) VALUES';

foreach( $UploadData AS $DataValue)
    $SQL .= sprintf(" ( '%s', '%s' ),", $DataValue['Name'], $DataValue['user'] );

$SQL = substr($SQL, -1);

$query = $db_conn->prepare($SQL);
$query->execute();
```

Result

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, user) VALUES ('VAL', 'VAL'), ('VAL', 'VAL') ....
```

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query?lq=1