# How should I use for (i++) in select data mysql? Is that possible?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I am doing tag insert. So, I have several tags need to be insert into mysql. I explode it first, then I have a array[0],array[1],array[2]......., and I need to SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=array[0] and key=array[1] and key=array[2]......., instead of doing this way, I want to use i++, however, it doesn't work, I don't know why? Help please! appreciate!

```html
<?php
       $tag=strtolower($_POST['tag']);
  $tag=explode(" ", $tag);
  include 'db_tag.php';

  for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++){
  
  $stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT key FROM keyword WHERE key = :tag"); 
   $tag_i=$tag[$i];
      
  $stmt->bindParam(':tag', $tag_i);
                                 }
     $stmt->execute();
  $row_tag = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($row_tag as $row_tag){
   echo $row_tag['key'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you make a `SELECT` when you have to `INSERT` the tags? If instead this is about _reading_ the tags from the database, then one `SELECT` should be enough.

Comment: I didn't paste the whole code. sorry to confuse you. I need to do the select first, then do the if statement and insert.

Comment: May I suggest that you review the questions you asked so far and see if there are any answers worth to be *accepted*, or at least give some feedback as to what's missing? If you keep asking without looking at answers properly, people will start downvoting/ignoring you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For a `SELECT` :

First construct your SQL code:

```
$stmt = 'SELECT columns FROM keyword WHERE key = :tag0');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++){
  $stmt .= ' OR key = :tag' . $i;
}
```

Then fill up the params:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($stmt);
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++){        
  $stmt->bindParam(':tag'+$i, $tag[$i]);
}
```

By the way, in your code you are trying to select a column (`key`) which is fixed in the `WHERE` predicates, it's probably not what you want, since you will get exactly the data you've put in the query parameters to begin with.

#### For an `INSERT`:

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query).

Comment: Thanks for you response. I had tried your code. But it didn't work.  I also tried to change $tag[i] to $tag[$i], but it's not working.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I think I wrote that code a bit hastily without double checking. It should be correct now (up to the column names in the query).

Comment: Thank you again. But you need to change the + to . for append. Then, it works. Appreciate your help.

Comment: check @AmhedDaou 's answer, it's better.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [IN STATEMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) (The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.)

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($tag), '?'));
$stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT key FROM keyword WHERE key IN ($in)"); 
$stmt->execute($tag);
```

The catch is to put as many question marks as parameters so use my code if it is dynamic otherwise you can hardcode it.