# Adding quotes to array values in php

Tags: php, mysql

The following script is used to implode values from a multidimensional array and insert into the mysql table. The table contains field data types of varchar and decimal. Since varchar type requires quotes and to avoid selectively placing quotes, I would like to put all values in quotes. How to implement it?

```
$values = array();
foreach ($data as $rowValues) {
    foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
            }

    $values[] = "(" . implode(', ', $rowValues) . ",'".$date."')";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO mem (memno,loan,subsc,intst, date)
          VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);
$result=mysql_query($query) or die();
```

I want the sql like this

```
INSERT INTO mem (memno,loan,subsc,intst, date)
values('value1', 'value2', 'valu3','value4','value5')
```

Comment: you could simply do this 
$values[] = "('" . implode("', '", $rowValues) . "','".$date."')";
but make sure your count of values ($rowValues) same as the count of table fields :)

Comment: And make sure you are validating these inputs before running the query

Comment: Your suggestion worked. How to validate the array?

Comment: Please reenter your comment as answer, so that I can accept it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query for a PDO example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use user input to build SQL strings - thats how you get SQL injection attacks.

[image: XKCD - Exploits of a mom]

Instead use [a prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    INSERT INTO mem( memno, loan, subsc, intst, date )
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
");
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $memno, $loan, $subsc, intst, $date);
```

### edit in response to the comment:

Dynamically binding an array of columns is pretty easy with PDO.

```
$db =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");

/**
* @param PDO $db
* @param string $table - the table to insert into
* @param array $columns - which columns do we want to insert into
* @param array $data - a key/value array of the data we want to insert
* @return bool
*/
function insert_into($db, $table, array $columns, array $data) {
    $rows = implode(', ', $fields);
    $placeholders = array_map ( function($key){ return ":$key" }, $fields); 
    $placeholders = implode(', ', $fields);
    
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO $table ($fields)
        VALUES ($placeholders);
    ";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    foreach( $fields as $field) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":$field", $data[$field]);
    }

    return $sth->execute();
}

$inserted = insertInto(
    $db
    'mem',
    array("memno", "loan", "subsc", "intst", "date"),
    $data
);
```

Notice that the columns to insert are defined separately.
If I had used:

```
array_keys($data);
```

It would lead to a [mass assigment vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) if `$data` comes from user input and is not whitelisted.

You can accomplish the same thing with `mysqli` but its a bit trickier.

Comment: I have not used prepared statement earlier. If you can re-frame my script given in the question, it would be helpful. Because in your answer memno, loan, subsc are given as variables. You can easily see from the script that I implode an array to get values

Comment: Added an example of how to dynamically assign from an array.

Answer (score 0):

If $rowValues array is as below then you can do like this also.

```
$rowValues = array(
  "memno"=>"a",
  "loan"=>"b",
  "subsc"=>"c",
  "intst"=>"d"
);

$fldStr = array();
$valStr = array();
foreach($rowValues as $key=>$val) {
  array_push($fldStr, $key);
  $v2 = "'" . $val . "'";
  array_push($valStr, $v2);
}
array_push($fldStr, "date");
array_push($valStr, "'" . $date . "'");

$flds = implode(", ", $fldStr);
$vals = implode(", ", $valStr);

$query = "INSERT INTO mem ($flds) values($vals)";
```