# For loop in PHP: How to make a loop interval?

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

I am trying to make a loop. Something like this:

I have 1000 records. Within this 1000 records it should take

> - first 200
> - then 201-400
> - then 401-600
> - then 600-800
> - then 801-1000

This is my code:

```
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){
if($i > 200){
//$this->db->save(); //save some data
break;
}

echo $i."<br>";

if($i == 200){
  for($i=201; $i<=400; $i++) {
  //$this->db->save();  //save some data
  echo $i."<br>";
   }
}

if($i == 400) {
  for($i=401; $i<=600; $i++){
     echo $i."<br>";
   }
 }
```

Part 2:

```
$totalClientCount = 1000;      

$input_array    =    range(1, $totalClientCount);
$chunks         =    array_chunk($input_array, 200);

foreach ($chunks as $k => $chunk) { 

if ($k == 0) {  // 0-200
  $this->db->where('AccountNo', $id);
  //$this->db->limit($offset,$limit);
  $getClientDetails = $this->db->get('table');
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($getClientDetails);    
}
```

This is where I am stuck. How do I execute this properly?

Comment: or loop in a loop

Comment: Instead of having a "main" loop with if-statements, why not simply have separate loops for the required ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)  here. Let me show an example with 100 entries, with first 20, 21-40, 41-60 and so on.

```
$input_array    =    range(1, 100);
$chunks         =    array_chunk($input_array, 20);
```

This is what $chunks array will look like:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        ......
        [9] => 10
     ),
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21
        [1] => 22
        .......
        [2] => 40
     )
     .........
     .........
   [4] => Array
      (
        [0] => 81
        [1] => 82
        ......
        [19] => 100 
   )
```

Now loop through your $chunks array.

```
foreach ($chunks as $k => $chunk) {
    /* $k = 0 means first 20 items */
    if ($k == 0) {
        // your code here
    }
    foreach ($chunk as $i) {
        echo $i;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply. But it should not go to another array until complete of first array[0]. i have test it is loading all at once 1000 records.just i need 0-200 and save some data, then array[1]

Comment: sorry for above comments.Its run perfectly what i was expecting thank you guys. @Object Manipulation,@Nishant Nair,@Anushil Nandan

Answer (score 1):

in case you are doing some task even after given range [200] you can use this:

```
$range = 200;
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){
  //$this->db->save();
  if ($i%$range == 0) {
    //...
  }
}
```

basically here you are calling `$this->db->save()` every time till the end of loop and just using 201,401,601,801 to do something else, like printing current value of `$i`

in case you want to do separate tasks after every range:

```
$range = 200;
$fn = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){
  $functionToCall = 'fn_'.$fn;
  $functionToCall();
  if ($i%$range == 0) {
    $fn = $i+1;
  }
}

function fn_0()
{
  //...
}

function fn_201()
{
  //...
}

function fn_401()
{
  //...
}

function fn_601()
{
  //...
}

function fn_801()
{
  //...
}
```

it's always a good practice to logically separate your functions.

Also if you have to just save 1000 times, do not use loop to insert. Try batch insert instead, something like [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052225/build-a-batch-query-for-mysql-insert-each-1000-items)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_splice`. If you need to send the array with specific interval its the best option.

I have implemented it in my code for sending notification for 1000 ids at a time.

```
$sendIds = array_splice($your_array,0,199);
```