# How do I insert multiple items using one insert statement while at the same time detect if a unique column has duplicate values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, pdo

Please mark it as duplicate if the same question exists already.

I am using MySQL to do the insertion, and I am using PDO prepared statements. I now want to insert an array of rows into a database. A similar question can be found here [Multiple Values Insert with PDO Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2098689/4984911). However, the author didn't consider the case when duplicates occur on unique column(s). For example, consider the following table:

```
id    name    counter
```

where `name` has unique property and whenever an existing `name` is trying to be inserted the counter increases by 1. Now I want to insert an array with three names as follows:

```
$name_array = array('User A','User B','User C');
```

Suppose my table currently has User A only and its corresponding counter is 1. In that case, I would like the table after insertion be as follows:

```
id    name      counter
1     User A    2
2     User B    1
3     User C    1
```

Is it possible for me to do it using one insert statement? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: IMHO this has nothing to do with PHP, PDO or prepared statements - it is about converting an `INSERT` into an `UPDATE` for special cases.

That being so, I would solve this by using the `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construct, somewhere along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO tablename(name)
VALUES ('User A'), ('User B'), ('User C')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1;
```

How you send this query to the MySQL server (be it PHP/PDO or whatever) should be of no importance.

Comment: OK,  so `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` can work in this manner. I didn't think of that! Thanks!