# PHP PDO multiple insert doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I follow the solution from this example: [PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)
, i dont have any error but insert doesnt work. This is the code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
        $fields = array('field1', 'field2',  'field3', 'field4');

        $pdo->beginTransaction();
        $insert_values = array();
        foreach ($dataForInsert as $key => $value) {
            $question_marks[] = '(' . $this->placeholders('?', sizeof($value)) . ')';
            $insert_values = array_merge($insert_values, array_values($value));
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (" . implode(",", $fields ) . ") VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        try {
            $stmt->execute($insert_values);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

where i am making mistake?

Comment: did you debug your code there may be some hidden sql warnings...

Comment: print_r($stmt) gives:
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => INSERT INTO live_collection_topic (field1,field2,field3,field4) VALUES (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?)

Comment: print_r($insert_values) gives: [0] => 10591
    [1] => 0062100000046
    [2] =>
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 3835
    [5] => 817
    [6] =>
    [7] =>

Comment: you are not defining the array in `foreach` my opinion it should be `foreach ($fields as $key => $value)`

Comment: $collectionTopicData is my data that i got from stored procedure, data that i want to insert. it gives me proper data that i posted in previous coment