# PDO beginTransaction failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting following error in my php error_log

> PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=29770 in /home/test/test.php on line 87

And on line 87 in my php script the code id

```
$DBH->beginTransaction();
```

And after that when i commit i get the following error

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /home/test/test.php:98

I have already set the `max_allowed_packet=512M` and my table is `InnoDB`

What is wrong here?

**EDIT:** My code is running in a loop to insert total 100,000+ records into the table i am doing 5000 multiple inserts in each transaction.
This is my code structure

```
beginTransaction
 Multiple insert query for 5000 records
commit
```

Running in a loop to insert 100,000+ records. Sometimes the script runs successfully sometimes it fails.

I get this error in the middle of 6-7 loops.(after inserting 30k to 40k records)

Comment: What code occurs before the `beginTransaction()` line? Please edit to show more context there. In particular, were there previous queries which may not have had all rows fetched, or other situations which may interfere with the connected state of `$DBH`.

Comment: what is the query you are tring to run like? give us an example

Comment: please give an example, or tell the size of operation you are doing

Comment: Also, what happens if you test without a transaction, executing plain `query()` or `prepare()/execute()` sequences instead? Same error, different error, or successful queries?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Check edit

Comment: I meant to post real code. The state of  the object `$DBH` is important. The queries themselves may be important. It sounds like you are losing the client connection to mysql, possibly because of a timeout, but if it fails inside the insert loop after 6-7 iterations, then it does not make sense that the error is reported at beginTransaction().

Comment: What does [`$DBH->inTransaction()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.intransaction.php) return after each insert?

Comment: PS, because MySQL is retarded, if you truncate, alter, or create a new table, inside a transaction, your transaction will be committed automatically and transaction ended, without warning, IIRC

Comment: Can you tell me the PHP version ?

Comment: Check this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63812

Comment: Doesn't this approach work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query

Comment: How long was the script running for?

Answer (score 1):

I did some web searching for the phrase "Error while sending QUERY packet." It was able to turn up this link: http://www.willhallonline.co.uk/blog/max-packet-size-php-error

The author of that post had a similar issue and also tried the "increase `max_allowed_packet` size" and increased timeouts as well but that didn't work. But what appears to have worked was splitting the job up into smaller chunks.

> Our new smaller csv files updated successfully inside MySQL, though we're still none the wiser as to what was causing the original error.

It's not clear to me whether they processed the many chunks within the lifespan of one PHP process or if they ran the code multiple times, but the idea seems sound; maybe you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

An other posibility is to write the data in a CSV file and use the MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load it to your database (here is the [link to MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loading-tables.html)).
I tryed this with CSV files sized up to 250MB and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the connection to the database is not persistent. This might cause the transactions to wipe out before commiting and hence the error.

I would have rather commented as this is not an "answer" per se , but unfortunately I dont have the required reputation.