# How to get data from multiple <li> elements with jQuery and send over php to MySQL table

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax

I have a menu something like this:

```
 <ul>
  <li data-id=1 data-gameresult=2:0></li>
  <li data-id=3 data-gameresult=1:0></li>
  <li data-id=4 data-gameresult=0:0></li>
  <li data-id=5 data-gameresult=1:3></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to get data **from each 'li' element** and send it over jquery ajax function to php file to create **single SQL query**.

I know how to use jquery ajax, something like:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "file.php",
data:{'id':id,'gameresult':gameresult}
});
```

But I can only send **one li's data** with this approach.

Comment: You have to create a JSON from your data and then give it to ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically there, right?

You've declared an object called `data`, which has 2 properties:

- `id`
- `gameresult`

You want to have an *array* of these objects, so PHP receives the whole lot in one go.

```
var json = {
   gameResults: []
};

$("li").each(function (i, li) {
   json.gameResults.push($(li).data('gameresult'));
});
```

This gives you a JSON object with everything as an array:

```
{"gameResults":["2:0","1:0","0:0","1:3"]}
```

Alternatively you can have an array of objects, so each ID/gamescore pair is maintained:

```
$("li").each(function (i, li) {
   json.gameResults.push({
       id: $(li).data('id'),
       gamescore: $(li).data('gameresult')
   });
});
```

...which gives:

```
{"gameResults": [
   {"id":1,"gamescore":"2:0"},
   {"id":3,"gamescore":"1:0"},
   {"id":4,"gamescore":"0:0"},
   {"id":5,"gamescore":"1:3"}
]}
```

Then just pass `json` to jQuery as your data value.

On the PHP side, you'll receive a post object with this associative (or numerically indexed) array - which you can craft into a bulk SQL insert.

JSFiddle demo:

- https://jsfiddle.net/ubkmjrg3/3/

---

### Update: Processing on the PHP side.

To get the object to your PHP script, adjust your AJAX request like so:

```
 $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: "file.php",
     data: json,
     success: function(data) {
         document.write("<pre>" + data);
     }
 });
```

(Note I've changed `data: ...` and added `success: ...`.  We now pass the `json` variable as the data property, and use a call-back to handle a successful AJAX request.  I won't go into detail on this subject - but rather point you to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  You should handle errors etc as well - everything you need is on that link.)

`file.php` will receive a `POST` request - which in PHP means there's an automagical global variable called `$_POST` which will contain some data from the AJAX request.  Again, I won't repeat what's in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) - but just remind you to validate and sanitize **everything** - you absolutely must not trust this data implicitly.  It could be anything, from anywhere, and it could be evil (like a [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)).

I've written a test `file.php` script:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Making a successful AJAX request to it (using the exact JavaScript above) returns some data (which appears in the JavaScript success call-back in the `data` parameter):

```
array(1) {
  ["gameResults"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["gamescore"]=>
      string(3) "2:0"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["gamescore"]=>
      string(3) "1:0"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["gamescore"]=>
      string(3) "0:0"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["gamescore"]=>
      string(3) "1:3"
    }
 }
```

It's getting a bit inception-like now ... so I'll explain what's happened.

The browser's JavaScript engine has grabbed the data from the `li` elements, crafted a JSON object, submitted it (asynchronously in the background - via AJAX) to `file.php`, which has literally "dumped" all the data it received back to the browser.

The `document.write(...)` was just a quick hack to debug what came back from `file.php` - or put it another way, it just outputs the PHP `var_dump(...)` result to the browser screen.  Behind the scenes, there's been a request made to the PHP script, some server-side processing, a response made back and then some client-side processing to finish! *#winning*

On the PHP side then, we can process the `$_POST` object (**remembering to sanitize everything!**) like a normal PHP array:

```
foreach ($_POST['gameResults'] as $gameResult) {
    print $gameResult['id'] . ' ==> ' . $gameResult['gamescore'] . "<br>";
}
```

We get output like this:

```
1 ==> 2:0
3 ==> 1:0
4 ==> 0:0
5 ==> 1:3
```

(We've just iterated the game results on the PHP side and formatted them as very basic HTML.)

I guess at this point you want to build a big bulk SQL insert?  That's a bit much for me to go into in this single post - so I'll suggest you [search stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query) (or open a new question) to find out about that.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it tommorow, but seems exactly what I need!

Comment: No problem - let me know if you need any more assistance

Comment: Okay, to be honest, I have no idea what to do with that stuff when it comes into my PHP file...

Comment: Updated with some hints to get you going :)

Comment: I've added some hints to get you going in the right direction.  I'm afraid I've not got the time to go into as much detail as I'd like ...  If you've got a friend who's done this sort of stuff before - I'd recommend getting some mentorship, otherwise it's just a long road of reading and learning I'm afraid!  It's fun though.  Looking to work as a PHP dev one day?

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help man, its detailed enough! A mentor would be great, but I really dont know anybody at the moment. I am learning front end developing right now, but I need to build some websites as a reference to get a job easier. Usually a friend does the back end stuff, but he isnt as motivated as me these days. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate all li element by using jquery map or each function.

```
var id = $('li').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-id');
}).get();

var gameresult = $('li').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-gameresult');
}).get();
```