# What exactly is the fact : when placed before execution, PDO prepared statements make multiple sql calls or not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, prepared-statement

I asked a question about the best way, performace-wise, to make multiple inserts( hundreds or even thousands) in prepared statements. See here for it [How to perform multiple MySQL inserts in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224115/how-to-perform-multiple-mysql-inserts-in-php).

In the course of answering the question, this old issue came up again : Do multiple SQL calls really take place in the following or not? :

```
$stmt = $dbLink->prepare( "INSERT INTO table SET id = :ID, 
                                             name = :name, 
                                             email = :email, 
                                             mobile = :mobile");

$stmt->bindParam( ':ID', $person->getID(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':name', $person->getName(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':email', $person->getEmail(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':mobile', $person->getMobile(), PDO::PARAM_STR );

foreach( $persons as $person ){

   $stmt->execute(); 
}
```

Please, I think something like this cannot be right and wrong at the same time. There has to be a fact about it; and I just don't know that fact.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should re-order your code a bit:

- the `$person` is not defined outside the loop (or is not what you think), so you will get warnings, and the `bindParam` will set empty values
- you will be inserting the same (empty) values in your `for` loop, since you never update the query parameters.

Do it like this, as was [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224115/how-to-perform-multiple-mysql-inserts-in-php#answer-34224326):

```
$stmt = $dbLink->prepare( "INSERT INTO table SET id = :ID, 
                                             name = :name, 
                                             email = :email, 
                                             mobile = :mobile");

foreach ( $persons as $person ) {

    $stmt->bindParam( ':ID', $person->getID(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':name', $person->getName(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':email', $person->getEmail(), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':mobile', $person->getMobile(), PDO::PARAM_STR );

    $stmt->execute(); 
}
```

Second, *every time* you run `$stmt->execute()` you are *executing a query*. Therefore, you will run `count( $persons )` queries. The prepared statement is a little bit faster, because the SQL query string only has to be parsed once.

This will run pretty fast, even for thousands of records. However, you may get a delay every time the database writes to disk; this is especially noticable with software RAID and slow disks. You can eliminate all but one of those delays by using [*transactions*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php):

```
$dbLink->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $dbLink->prepare( ..... );
foreach ( $persons as $person ) {
  ...bindParam();
  ...execute();
}

$dbLink->commit();
```

Comment: I will edit as per the first point raised. I did not bother to re-order because I was not particular about that here. Besides, I am not showing all of my code. I could even have $person initialised somewhere before binding. So, while I understand what you pointed out about warning, I have my ways of dealing with that. As for the second, I will get back after I discover that myself.