# How to insert multiple record using PHP MySQL and PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lumen, multiple-records

I found this type of question on stack overflow and other website but none of the solution work in my project.

I am working in Lumen Laravel micro-framework for API and I want to insert multiple record with single query.

below is the code for single record insert and working fine.This code is for **follow category by user**. So when user click on **Follow Category** button this query is run and insert one record in database with **user_id** and **category_id** field.

```
 public function insertUserFollow($category){

    $sql = " INSERT INTO news_user_category_following
             SET
              user_id = :user_id,
              category_id = :category_id
            ";
    $sth = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

    $sth->bindParam(":user_id", $category['user_id']);
    $sth->bindParam(":category_id", $category['category_id']);

    $status  = $sth->execute();

    if(TRUE == $status){
        return $status;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Using above code my database looks like this :

```
user_id | category_id

 ------ | ------

    1   |   5
```

Now How I want to insert is below :

```
user_id | category_id

 ------ | ------

    1   |   5
    1   |   2
    1   |   3
    1   |   6
    1   |   4
    1   |   1
```

So, I want multiple record to be inserted by single query and all data are coming dynamic so how can I manage for each look in  query.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you are inserting only a few records, this is a huge waste of effort. If you are inserting a lot of data, there are lots of other more efficient ways such as LOAD DATA INFILE rather than generating queries in PHP.

Comment: @e4c5 I want to insert more than one record and it's not specify that it will be 5 or 10 records. it will be depend on user input. And I want to done this with PDO query

Comment: What have you already tried to achieve this?

Comment: @Andre I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query

Comment: you would have spent at least half an hour on this task by now. Once you complete it you will be able to save about 0.005 seconds per page load.