# Best practice inserting array to DB with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to add array content to database. For it i'm using

```
$arr = ["10","11","12","13"];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (user_id, view) VALUES (:user_id, :view)";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $value);
    $stmt->bindParam(':view', 'small');
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

is that good practice or bad? Is there any other good way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proper example is something like this:

```
$arr = ["10","11","12","13"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (`user_id`, `view`) VALUES (:user_id, :view)";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
     $stmt->execute(array('user_id' => $value, 'view' => 'small'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always `execute()` with an array:

```
$stmt->execute(array('user_id' => $value, 'view' => 'small'));
```

That usually minimizes your code, and it also allows you to accumulate data through `if` clauses as you build up a query without having to complicate your code.

Also as @u_mulder points out, you only need to `prepare` your query once as it doesn't change through each iteration of that loop.