# PHP PDO Insert Statement exceeding execution time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am inserting bulk values using prepared statements, assigning values and execution  is done in loop still it is taking too long and exceeding the execution limit.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['mov_id']) && isset($_GET['season']))
{
$id= $_GET['mov_id'];
$season = $_GET['season'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mov_movies` where moviesID =:id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$imdbID = $row['IMDBid'];


if(isset($_POST['btn-addmovie']))
{
$episodes = trim($_POST['tepisodes']);

    $name = "";
     $episode = "";
     $DOR = "";
     $IMDB = "";
     $drive = "";
     $cdn = "";

     $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("DELETE FROM `mov_season` where movId =:id");
     $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
     $count = 1;

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO `mov_season` (`movId`, `season`, `episode`, `releaseDate`, `IMDB`, `driveLink`, `cdnLink` , `title`) VALUES (:id, :season, :episode,:releaseDate, :IMDB,:drive,:cdn,:name)");
    $stmt->bindparam(":id", $id);
       $stmt->bindparam(":season", $season);
       $stmt->bindparam(":episode", $episode);  
       $stmt->bindparam(":releaseDate", $DOR);  
       $stmt->bindparam(":IMDB", $IMDB ); 
       $stmt->bindparam(":drive", $drive ); 
       $stmt->bindparam(":cdn", $cdn );
       $stmt->bindparam(":name", $name);
     while($count < $episodes){

     $name = trim($_POST['name'.$count]);
     $episode = trim($_POST['episode'.$count]);
     $DOR = trim($_POST['DOR'.$count]);
     $IMDB = trim($_POST['imdb'.$count]);
     $drive = trim($_POST['drive'.$count]);
     $cdn = trim($_POST['cdn'.$count]);

     if(($drive != "") || ($cdn = "")){



       $stmt->execute();

       $count++;
     }




    }
     $success = "Successfully Updated!";



 }
 }
```

Statement is taking place in if loop inside while loop. And even for only one execution it exceeds 120 sec of execution time.

Comment: how many records we talking here? Also this isn't a proper bulk insert, you're executing a statement every record, rather than say 1 statement per 1,000 records.

Comment: why dont you try bulk insert using PDO

Comment: Usually there are only 10 records at max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem. You're only incrementing $count if this condition is true, which means you're probably in an infinite loop.

```
if(($drive != "") || ($cdn = "")){
    $stmt->execute();
    $count++;
}
```

Do this instead, so $count is always incremented.

```
if(($drive != "") || ($cdn = "")){
    $stmt->execute();
}
$count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using bulk insert. In this you  have to execute on single query which will insert multiple records

[PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)