# PDO bind multiple values in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im working with a lot of sql queries. While I have not mastered PDO yet I was hoping to come here for a bit of help since my previous searches didn't deliver much in terms of help. I did come across [this link on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query) but it seems a bit out of scope to what I am doing

Consider The following code, which works 100%;

```
public function composeMsg($userID, $toUser, $subject, $msg, $sentOn ){
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (userID, fromID, subject, body, senton) values (:userID, :toUser, :subject, :msg, :sentOn )";
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        //NOT EFFICIENT
        $stmnt->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':toUser', $toUser);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':subject', $subject);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':msg', $msg);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':sentOn', $sentOn);

        $stmnt->execute();
        if($stmnt->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }//FUNCTION
```

Im finding myself to continuously type `$stmnt->bindValue(':value', $value)` multiple times *as can be seen from the code above*. **Im looking for a build in PDO function or something similar which I can make use of to avoid all the repetition.**

Any advise welcomed

Comment: Thanks Nigel I just had a peek will inspect it more. The frustrating thing for beginners like myself is that the PHP Manual can often be over complicated and hard to grasp, with many examples being overkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding them all as part of the execute...

```
   $stmnt->execute([':userID'=> $userID,
         ':toUser'=> $toUser,
         ':subject' => $subject,
         ':msg' => $msg,
         ':sentOn' => $sentOn]);
```

Comment: That I get Thanks Mate