# In PHP, when I use $dbh->prepare($query)->execute($values) with placeholders, how can I INSERT multiple records one time?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$query = 'INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)';
$values = [
    [1, 'Mary'],
    [2, 'Peter'],
    [3, 'Mike']
];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

I know the above codes will cause errors. But if I want to INSERT multiple records with placeholders conveniently, how can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

Comment: OK, thank you very much! It seems that there aren't "elegant" ways to achieve this.

Comment: There is not really a need for one ... with prepared statements, statement and data are send to the database independently from each other. So you can bind parameters and then execute the statement in a loop; this does not slow things down as sending a “traditional” statement for individual row inserts multiple times would.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful instructions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe has provided good answers for this question. Please refer to the above comments, and especially refer to the link that he posted, which has more detailed discussions within it.