# query insert only one row instead multiple rows

Tags: php, pdo, bulkinsert

I was trying to insert multiple values from the excel sheet, I got all data from excel sheet to an array variable. but when I insert it always inserts the 1st row only, I have a method to execute insert query by using PDO,

My Data

```
array (size=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'A' => string '*' (length=1)
      'B' => string 'Title' (length=5)
      'C' => string 'Author' (length=6)
      'D' => string 'Publication ' (length=12)
      'E' => string 'Container' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'A' => float 1
      'B' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      'C' => string 'one' (length=3)
      'D' => string 'two' (length=3)
      'E' => string 'X1' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      'A' => float 2
      'B' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      'C' => string 'three' (length=5)
      'D' => string 'four' (length=4)
      'E' => string 'X2' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      'A' => float 3
      'B' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      'C' => string 'five' (length=4)
      'D' => string 'six' (length=3)
      'E' => string 'X3' (length=2)
```

This my method

```
public function importBooks($data, $nr)
{
    // Init query
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO books_pre (title, author, publication, container, created_by, created_at) VALUES (:title, :author, :publication, :container, :created_by, now())');

    for ($i=2; $i<$nr; $i++) {
        // Bind values
        $this->db->bind(':title', $data[$i]['B']);
        $this->db->bind(':author', $data[$i]['C']);
        $this->db->bind(':publication', $data[$i]['D']);
        $this->db->bind(':container', $data[$i]['E']);
        $this->db->bind(':created_by', $_SESSION['user_id']);

        // Execute query
        if ($this->db->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your are calling the method in a loop?

Comment: yes im calling bind method, from my database class

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? Is the loop running properly from `2` till the number you expect? Is the data used in the `bind` call the one you expect?

Comment: yes, I checked the values, I am looping the number of rows from excel sheet its correct, and the values on binding method also correct

Comment: You are exiting the function after the first insert with "return"

Comment: @NoBBy is that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [return statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) will end the execution of your method -- and exit the loop. To quote the manual:

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call.

To make this work, with minimal effort, I'd only `return false` when `$this->db->execute()` fails and `return true` at the end of your method, like so:

```
public function importBooks($data, $nr)
{
    // Init query
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO books_pre (title, author, publication, container, created_by, created_at) VALUES (:title, :author, :publication, :container, :created_by, now())');

    for ($i=2; $i<$nr; $i++) {
        // Bind values
        $this->db->bind(':title', $data[$i]['B']);
        $this->db->bind(':author', $data[$i]['C']);
        $this->db->bind(':publication', $data[$i]['D']);
        $this->db->bind(':container', $data[$i]['E']);
        $this->db->bind(':created_by', $_SESSION['user_id']);

        // Execute query
        if (!$this->db->execute()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, if I had to rewrite this code, I'd personally probably implode the data array and insert it all in one query.

Comment: why you saying that you will implode the data, is it improve performance?

Comment: @Looper It may improve performance, although it won't be noticeable in this example. However, if you had a bigger dataset (let's say 10,000 rows) you'll be sending a lot of queries -- probably too many, too fast. In that case it would be better practice, if you'd ask me, to insert it in several larger chunks.

Comment: i have more than 5000 rows, so is there any better way to insert this much properly?

Comment: Yeah, I'd insert it in a couple of large chunks. Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query) help you out?

Comment: No that post really confusing me, I don't know what to do on that, I was trying insert by my method its giving error as its taking more than 30 sec, please help with this

Comment: That's probably worth a new question, since your now running into another problem. Unless you've already figured it out ofc.