# how to Insert multiple arrays with multiple rows into MySQL using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple arrays into MySql database using PHP PDO. Its inserting duplicated row and it is not inserting the way I required. below is my code

HTML

```
             <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> Enter Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" placeholder="Product Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> No. of Pieces</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcount[]" placeholder="No.Of Items"/>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <label class="col-form-label"> Estimated Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estamount[]" placeholder="Estimated Amount of Each"/>
                    </div>
                    <p class="pull-left">Amount: &nbsp;<div class="Amount"></div></p>
                </div>
```

And PHP Code is

```
$totalamount=0;
        foreach($_POST['pname'] as $proname){

            foreach($_POST['pcount'] as $quantity){

                foreach($_POST['estamount'] as $estamount){

                    $totalamount = $quantity*$estamount;

                    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `order`(custname, contact, product_name, quantity, est_amount, advance_paid, delivery_period, date, status, total_amount, orderid) VALUES(:custname, :contact, :product_name, :quantity, :est_amount, :advance_paid, :delivery_period, :date, :status, :total_amount, :orderid)";
                    $query=$dbh->prepare($sql);
                    $query->bindParam(':custname',$custmorname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':contact',$contact,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':product_name',$proname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':quantity',$quantity,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':est_amount',$estamount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':advance_paid',$advancepaid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':delivery_period',$delevery,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':date',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':orderid',$orderid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(':total_amount',$totalamount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->execute();
                    }
              }
        }
```

I would like to insert `$proname , $quantity , $est_amount` in one record and its should insert multiple recodes as per inserted values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

Comment: please read my question carefully. I have multiple arrays with multiple rows

Comment: Ahd that makes it a non-duplicate because....??? You've only written that "it is not inserting the way I required", but not what exactly you require

Comment: @NicoHaase  If you feel that it's a possible duplicate, it's best to "flag" it as one instead of typing it out as a comment. When it gets flagged, it shows up somewhere that others may pickup on voting to close as such also. Also, if I or someone else who can hammer it with it in one go, then that too will show your name on it, rather than just the person who hammered it. Just thought I'd let you know how voting to close works. Why I think you did that would probably be that you can't "vote" to close as a duplicate. Right you are, *but* you can "flag" as a duplicate though.

Comment: Well, thats what I did: flag it. That comment was written automatically

Comment: @NicoHaase You should ping me as I did for you. I only saw your comment because I'm still in here. I find it odd that it doesn't already show a "1" under the "close" option though. Possible bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a nested for loop it will definitely lead for duplicate records. Let me make a quick correction.

```
$totalamount=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pname']); $i++){
    $proname = $_POST['pname'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['pcount'][$i];
    $estamount = $_POST['estamount'][$i];
    $totalamount = $quantity*$estamount;

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `order`(custname, contact, product_name, quantity, est_amount, advance_paid, delivery_period, date, status, total_amount, orderid) VALUES(:custname, :contact, :product_name, :quantity, :est_amount, :advance_paid, :delivery_period, :date, :status, :total_amount, :orderid)";
    $query=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':custname',$custmorname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':contact',$contact,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':product_name',$proname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':quantity',$quantity,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':est_amount',$estamount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':advance_paid',$advancepaid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':delivery_period',$delevery,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':date',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':orderid',$orderid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':total_amount',$totalamount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();


}
```