# How to insert array value in Implode form in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have a value in below format and i want to convert this key and value in implode form to insert value in database in mysql.

```
 Array
(
[users_ids] => 
[key_name] => Total_Cubic_Metres
[value_name] => 3.46m³
)

Array
(
[users_ids] => 
[key_name] => Bedroom_Bassinette
[value_name] => 2
)

Array
(
[users_ids] => 
[key_name] => Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers
[value_name] => 2
)

Array
(
[users_ids] => 
[key_name] => Bedroom_Bedside_Table
[value_name] => 2
)
```

I have 2 COLUMN in MYSQL "key" and "value" and store the above value in this field in implode form something like this 
key:Total_Cubic_Metres,Bedroom_Bassinette,Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers,Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers,Bedroom_Bedside_Table

Value:3.46m³, 2, 2,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [bindParam](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-use-php-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database) ([PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)) and write your queries like so:

```
$my_Insert_Statement = $my_Db_Connection->prepare("
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (
  Total_Cubic_Metres,
  Bedroom_Bassinette,
  Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers,
  Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers,
  Bedroom_Bedside_Table) 
VALUES (
 :Total_Cubic_Metres,  
 :Bedroom_Bassinette,
 :Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers,
 :Bedroom_Bedside_Drawers,
 :Bedroom_Bedside_Table
)");
```

and you could add them like:

```
foreach($arr as $colData){
  $my_Insert_Statement->bindParam($colData['key_name'], $colData['value_name']);
}
```

and execute the prepared statement:

```
if ($my_Insert_Statement->execute()) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Unable to create record";
}
```

Comment: in form there are so many value like "Bedroom_Bassinette" so how can i define this

Comment: @Sheenu multiple inserts? You could iterate through this code a couple of times or you could build an insert multiple function to handle the multiple rows you would like to insert.

Comment: I have a form in which there are 150 fields and i want to insert only that value which have data and i have that value which have data in above array format but i want to store that data in 1 row , because currently its stored in multiple row

Comment: You would have to select the row you would like to insert and then build and prepare a query for it. How do you determine which row[s] you would like to insert? Perhaps you are looking for `array_filter()`(to filter out the record)?

Comment: foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if ($key != 'submit') {
        if($value!='') {
                 
        $info = array(          
    'key_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string($key),
    'value_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string($value),
    
    );}}}

Comment: from above code i found the key and value which have data

Comment: Then why can't you insert this row?

Comment: its stored in multiple row but  i want to store all value in one row

Comment: Take a look at this answer here, this may be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/2098689/5066625. If it is, let me know and I will rescind my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 function insertQuery($table, $dataArray, $connection){
    $dataArray = array_map(array($connection, 'real_escape_string'), $dataArray);
    $keys = array_keys($dataArray);
    $colmuns = implode(",",$keys);
    $values =array_values($dataArray);
    $valueData = implode("','",$values);
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($colmuns) VALUES ('$valueData')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($result){
      $id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
      return $id;
    }
    return false;
 }
```