# How to add an external variable with BULK INSERT DATA in php?

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, pdo

I have a large csv file (over 100,000 lines) encoded in UTF-8-BOM  that looks like this:

```
27336;00203-AND1;90-BLACK;9.5;2
27336;00203-ET1;90-BLACK;10;1
27336;00203-ET1;90-BLACK;12;1
...
```

And a table in my SQL Server database with these columns :

```
storenumber | stylecode | colour | size | units | timestamp
```

I use Bulk Insert Data to load the file at once, but I would like to add my $timestamp variable to each line inserted in my table but it doesn't work... How do I do it?

```
 <?php

include("connexion.php");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 32400);
$timestamp= date("y-m-d H:i");


$csv= "D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/files/BI2_20200720_1344_00076.txt";

                     $query = "BULK INSERT dbo.Y2_Inventory 
                    FROM '$csv' 
                    WITH (
                    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', 
                    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                    ERRORFILE = 'myfileerror.log'
                     )";

                     $stmt = $conn->query( $query );     
                     if (!$stmt) { echo $conn->error;} 


$query2 = "UPDATE dbo.Y2_Inventory SET timestamp = ? WHERE timestamp IS NULL";

                     $stmt = $conn->query( $query2 );     
                    
            
        echo "good";        

?>
```

Comment: You can't parametrise a `BULK INSERT` you have to use dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the values (something you are not doing here).

Comment: I wanted to use BULK INSERT because otherwise the processing of my file takes hours... can I improve the insertion speed? @Larnu

Comment: @Eric27 What do you expect from `LASTROW = '$timestamp'`? `LASTROW` simply specifies the number of the last row to load. You may try to execute and additional `UPDATE` after the `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: But if I do it afterwards, won't he insert my $timestamp in every line of my table? @Zhorov

Comment: I assume that on inserting the `timestamp` column is `NULL`, so `UPDATE .. SET timestamp = ? WHERE timestamp IS NULL` should wortk.

Comment: I updated my code, do you think I should do it like this? @Zhorov

Comment: Can you succesfully execute `BULK INSERT` command in an external tool (like SQL Server Management Studio), because your table has `6` columns, but you have only `5` columns in the data file? if not you'll need a format file with mappings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218517/discussion-between-eric27-and-zhorov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the following:

- Always try to use parameters in your statement (of course if possible) or carefully sanitize the input data. In this specific case you may try to check if the input file exists and after that inject filename in your statement.
- The input data doesn't match the table definition, so you may try to import the data in a temporary table.
- Pass `datetime` values as text using an unambiguous format (e.g. `2020-07-25T12:00:00`).

The following example is a possible solution to your problem:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Y2_Inventory (
    storenumber int,
    stylecode nvarchar(50),
    colour nvarchar(50),
    size numeric(10, 1), 
    units int,
    [timestamp] datetime
)
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
//
include("connexion.php");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 32400);

// CSV file
$csv = "D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/files/BI2_20200720_1344_00076.txt";  
$err = "D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/files/BI2_20200720_1344_00076.err";
if (!file_exists($csv)) {
    die("CSV file not exists.");    
}
    
// Time stamp
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");

// INSERT Data
try {
    $query = "
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
        SELECT storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units
        INTO #t
        FROM Y2_Inventory
        WHERE 1 = 0;
        
        BULK INSERT #t 
        FROM '$csv' 
        WITH (
            ERRORFILE = '$err',
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', 
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
        );
        
        INSERT INTO Y2_Inventory (storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, [timestamp])
        SELECT storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, ?
        FROM #t;
    
        DROP TABLE #t;
    ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);     
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $timestamp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "OK";        
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ("Error executing query. ".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: @Eric27 It is a working example, tested with SQL Server 2017, PHP 7.4.8 and PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.8.

Comment: Have you tested with a csv file encoded in UTF-8-BOM?Because my files are encoded like this and it was causing me problems I had to do a 'fseek($handle, 3);' to ignore the BOM when reading my file when I was using fgetcsv @Zhorov

Comment: I had used it to insert my csv data into my table but it took me several hours to record all the lines... That's why I looked for a solution to go faster and I think it's the best to insert data from big csv files? @Zhorov

Comment: Do you think you could show me an example with the 1000 rows? I'd like to compare the two methods to see which one takes the least time for large csv files @Zhorov

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query but I'm having trouble adapting it to my situation... @Zhorov

Comment: @Eric27 It's an exellent starting point. If you have troubles implementing this solution, you may ask a question with the problems you face. I'm sure most of us will try to help you.

Comment: And if I want to put in a txt file the erroneous lines that are not inserted in the table, how can I do it? @Zhorov

Comment: @Eric27 `ERRORFILE` option in `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218711/discussion-between-eric27-and-zhorov).

Comment: When I use your code the file doesn't fit into my database... It's very strange @Zhorov

Comment: No on the page I did display "OK" during execution @Zhorov

Comment: Does the table definition from the example in the answer match your actual table definition? If possible, post the table definition in the question. Also, I've made an update and the `BULK INRT` includes `ERRORFILE` option. Does this file contain any errors?

Comment: I used your table definition and your code to make sure I have the same thing and the error file will not be created in the folder in question @Zhorov

Comment: @Eric27 I've tested and double-tested the example. If the `CSV` has data with formatting errors and cannot be converted, the error file is created and the excpetion is generated, but the correct data is inserted into the table. Change the file location and use a folder with the appropriate permissions. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put your file so that your SQL Server can access it? @Zhorov

Comment: I found my mistake, when I test directly into the database I have: Cannot bulk load because the file ... could not be opened. Operating system error code (null)

Comment: @Eric27, For the test in the`D:\\` folder.

Comment: Ok the error comes from there because I have my files which are on my web server and not on my SQL Server @Zhorov

Comment: Wondering what `INSERT INTO WHERE 1 = 0` means ... Didn't know it a nice way to create a new table from another table schema ;)

Comment: @HrvojeT, it's simply a `WHERE` clause, that returns `FALSE`, so the inserted rows are always zero.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mention in the comment, you can't parametrise a `BULK INSERT` statement. Therefore you have to use Dynamic SQL. I don't know/write PHP, however, the above I can clearly see is **wide** open to injection, as you're simply injecting the file's name into the SQL statement. You ***need*** to fix that, and parametrise your statement [How to: Perform Parameterized Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries?view=sql-server-ver15).

As for the SQL, this will look something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @FilePath nvarchar(256); --This would be your parameter, so might not bneed a declaration

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'BULK INSERT dbo.Y2_Inventory 
FROM N''' + REPLACE(@FilePath,'''','''''') + N'''
     WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',
          FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
          ERRORFILE = ''myfileerror.log'');';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your Best Friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so now I have to adapt this sql code in php to execute it in my code? @Larnu

Comment: Correct, as I said, I don't write PHP, so I have omitted that, however, I have linked you on the documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Your code corrects sql injections but not to add my last $timestamp column at the same time? @Larnu

Comment: That's a completely different query, @Eric27 . I was addressing the `BULK INSERT`, as that's the part you're having the problem with,.